# persist ethtool settings between reboots

Tags: linux, networking, redhat-enterprise-linux

RHEL Deployment Guide [suggests following](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Deployment_Guide/#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0):

---

ETHTOOL_OPTS=options
where options are any device-specific options supported by ethtool. For example, if you wanted to force 100Mb, full duplex:
ETHTOOL_OPTS="autoneg off speed 100 duplex full"

Instead of a custom initscript, use ETHTOOL_OPTS to set the interface speed and duplex settings. Custom initscripts run outside of the network init script lead to unpredictable results during a post-boot network service restart.

---

I'v added ETHTOOL_OPTS to my configs, reboot server, but settings was not applied. Why my change doesn't work and how to make it works? I expect `rx-usecs` to be `0`.

`[oleg@localhost ~]$ service NetworkManager status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  NetworkManager.service
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
[oleg@localhost ~]$ ethtool -c enp2s0f1 | grep rx-usecs
rx-usecs: 58
rx-usecs-irq: 58
rx-usecs-low: 0
rx-usecs-high: 0
[oleg@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0f1
DEVICE=enp2s0f1
NAME=enp2s0f1Name
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0F:13:24:73:A1
ETHTOOL_OPTS="rx-usecs 0"`

Indicating that `NetworkManager` is disabled on my system because of this issue https://access.redhat.com/solutions/878503

Comment: First you should read the correct documentation. The doc you posted is not for the OS you are running. You have RHEL 7 but that document is for RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since. But I think you should use `ETHTOOL_OPTS="-C enp2s0f1 rx-usecs 0"` instead. If you just specify `rx-usecs 0`, it will actually execute  `ethtools -s enp2s0f1 rx-usecs 0`